# End session screen not close automatically after login

Tags: login, session

I configured the login screen and the login process for my purposes.
but there is an issue I don't know how to solve.
after the session ends, there is a pop-up with a login screen called "wp-auth-check", but after I logged-in by this screen, [image]the window not closing automatically like before I configured the screen, how do I make the window close automatically after the login?

Comment: If the window does not close, what happens instead?

Comment: the log-in happens inside the window, and I'm already logged-in in the main window to, and if I close this pop-up, the behavior like It closed automatically, so I just need to find a way to close this window automatically.

Comment: I don't understand. You have the pop up, your login has expired, and you need to log in again, so you fill in your user/pass and submit. What happens next? Are you describing broken behaviour? If you're already logged in and the pop up appears but it shouldn't, is that the problem you're trying to solve? That your login immediatley expires? This pop up should only display if your login expires which can take days to happen. If this pops up on every single page then that's a different problem

Comment: my login succeeds but the problem is that the pop up doesn't close automatically after the log-in. if I close with the "X" button every thing o.k, but I just want to know how to close this screen automatically and not with the "X" button.

Comment: Is this the default WordPress login or have you replaced it in some way? It looks odd to me.